# Why is Texpad not showing the PDF?

Tags: pdf, compiling, mactex, texpad

I have a question regarding the Typesetter Texpad for macOS. Ususally I use Overleaf but I thought about switching to a local typesetter. I searched for some and ended up downloading the tial version of Texpad after trying various other typesetters. I really love the environment and design of Texpad, also the tree design of all the chapters and so on (unlike MacTex/TexShop). But I have a really weird problem and I cannot figure it out and the Texpad support does not answer me.
When i want to typeset to get the preview of the PDF, Texpad does not show anything (see screenshot). [image] I use the MacTex Typesetter because the integrated Typesetter does not work with this thesis template that I want to use (which btw also does not show the pdf).
I really hope some of you guys can help me!
Thanks

Comment: You have the .cls file highlighted. Is that the file you're trying to compile? If so, that's not the file you need to compile. You need to compile a .tex file. Apologies if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, I did not compile the cls file. There's a TeX file in the tree, which starts with the letter D and it's not popping up because the tree is kinda long. But weirdly, texpad shows me that it did compile something (page 1 of 39). What I forgot to mention maybe is that both typesetters (the internal one and with mactex) nothing is shows up on the output side. Not even a standard template of texpad itself. Is it maybe a hardware problem? But then why can I compile with Texshop, which is included in mactex? I'm so very confused.

Comment: TeXShop is an editor, not an actual typsetting engine. When you say that nothing "shows up on the output side" that implies that you tried to compile your document either from inside an editor like TeXShop or from the command line. If your document compiles from inside TeXShop, then something else is going on. Can you provide more details?